# Testing a DSPComplex ROM

Tags: chisel

I'm working on building a DSPComplex ROM still and have hit what I think may be an actual Chisel problem.

I've built the ROM, can generate a verilog output from the code that looks reasonable, but can't seem to test the module with even the most basic of testers.  I've simplified it below to the most basic checking.

The error is a stack overflow like the following:

```
$ sbt 'testOnly taylor.TaylorTest'
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=8G; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/jcondley/Zendar/kodo/ZenFPGA/chisel/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to zen-chisel (in build file:/home/jcondley/Zendar/kodo/ZenFPGA/chisel/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/jcondley/Zendar/kodo/ZenFPGA/chisel/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[warn] there were 5 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/jcondley/Zendar/kodo/ZenFPGA/chisel/target/scala-2.12/test-classes ...
[warn] there were two deprecation warnings (since chisel3, will be removed by end of 2017); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] there were two feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] two warnings found
[info] Done compiling.
[info] [0.004] Elaborating design...
[deprecated] DspComplex.scala:22 (1029 calls): isLit is deprecated: "isLit is deprecated, use litOption.isDefined"
[deprecated] DspComplex.scala:22 (1029 calls): litArg is deprecated: "litArg is deprecated, use litOption or litTo*Option"
[deprecated] DspComplex.scala:23 (1029 calls): isLit is deprecated: "isLit is deprecated, use litOption.isDefined"
[deprecated] DspComplex.scala:23 (1029 calls): litArg is deprecated: "litArg is deprecated, use litOption or litTo*Option"
[warn] There were 4 deprecated function(s) used. These may stop compiling in a future release - you are encouraged to fix these issues.
[warn] Line numbers for deprecations reported by Chisel may be inaccurate; enable scalac compiler deprecation warnings via either of the following methods:
[warn]   In the sbt interactive console, enter:
[warn]     set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
[warn]   or, in your build.sbt, add the line:
[warn]     scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")
[info] [1.487] Done elaborating.
Total FIRRTL Compile Time: 1887.8 ms
Total FIRRTL Compile Time: 770.6 ms
End of dependency graph
Circuit state created
[info] TaylorTest:
[info] TaylorWindow
[info] taylor.TaylorTest *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.lang.StackOverflowError:
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:264)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.$anonfun$resolveDependency$1(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:453)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.Timer.apply(Timer.scala:40)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.resolveDependency(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:445)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.getValue(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:81)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:304)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.$anonfun$resolveDependency$1(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:453)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.Timer.apply(Timer.scala:40)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.resolveDependency(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:445)
[info]   at firrtl_interpreter.LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.getValue(LoFirrtlExpressionEvaluator.scala:81)
[info]   ...
```

This looks suspiciously like another ROM issue from here:

https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/642

but trying Chick's response here:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xss2M  -Duser.timezone=GMT"
```

seems to not solve the issue (and one of the options, MaxPermSize is ignored)

Is this a legitimate Chisel bug with ROMs or is something else going on here?

Actual module with the ROM:

```
package taylor

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.experimental.FixedPoint
import dsptools.numbers._
import scala.io.Source


class TaylorWindow(len: Int, window: Seq[FixedPoint]) extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val d_valid_in = Input(Bool())
        val sample = Input(DspComplex(FixedPoint(16.W, 8.BP), FixedPoint(16.W, 8.BP)))
        val windowed_sample = Output(DspComplex(FixedPoint(32.W, 8.BP), FixedPoint(32.W, 8.BP)))
        val d_valid_out = Output(Bool())
    })
     val win_coeff = VecInit(window.map(x=>DspComplex.wire(x, FixedPoint(0, 16.W, 8.BP))).toSeq) // ROM storing our coefficients.       

    io.d_valid_out := io.d_valid_in
    val counter = RegInit(UInt(10.W), 0.U)

    // Implicit reset
    io.windowed_sample:= io.sample * win_coeff(counter)
    when(io.d_valid_in) {
        counter := counter + 1.U
    }
}

object TaylorDriver extends App {                                                                                                       
    val filename = "src/test/test_data/taylor_coeffs"                                                                                   
    val coeff_file = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines                                                                                 
    val double_coeffs = coeff_file.map(x => x.toDouble)                                                                                 
    val fp_coeffs = double_coeffs.map(x => FixedPoint.fromDouble(x, 16.W, 8.BP))                                                        
    val fp_seq = fp_coeffs.toSeq                                                                                                        
    chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new TaylorWindow(1024, fp_seq))                                                                  
}
```

Tester Code:

```
package taylor

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.experimental.FixedPoint
import dsptools.numbers.implicits._
import scala.io.Source


import chisel3.iotesters
import chisel3.iotesters.{ChiselFlatSpec, Driver, PeekPokeTester}

class TaylorWindowUnitTest(dut: TaylorWindow) extends PeekPokeTester(dut) {

    val filename = "src/test/test_data/taylor_coeffs"
    val coeff_file = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
    val double_coeffs = coeff_file.map(x => x.toDouble)
    val fp_coeffs = double_coeffs.map(x => FixedPoint.fromDouble(x, 16.W, 8.BP))
    val fp_seq = fp_coeffs.toSeq

  poke(dut.io.d_valid_in, Bool(false))
  expect(dut.io.d_valid_out, Bool(false))
}

class TaylorTest extends ChiselFlatSpec {
    behavior of "TaylorWindow"

    backends foreach {backend =>
        it should s"test the basic Taylow Window" in {
            Driver(() => new TaylorWindow(1024, getSeq()), backend)(c => new TaylorWindowUnitTest(c)) should be (true)
        }
    }

  def getSeq() : Seq[FixedPoint] = {
    val filename = "src/test/test_data/taylor_coeffs"
    val coeff_file = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
    val double_coeffs = coeff_file.map(x => x.toDouble)
    val fp_coeffs = double_coeffs.map(x => FixedPoint.fromDouble(x, 16.W, 8.BP))
    fp_coeffs.toSeq
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a failure in the firrtl-interpreter (one of the Scala based Chisel simulator) which can have problems with a number of large firrtl constructs. If you have verilator installed can you try changing

```
backends foreach {backend =>
```

to

```
Seq("verilator") foreach {backend =>
```

and see what happens. Another think to try is Treadle which is the new version of the interpreter and is not in full release yet but is available in snapshot versions of the chisel ecosystem. It should be able to handle this also.